# How to interpret the debug output from Amavis->Spamassassin?

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, troubleshooting, debugging, amavis

Could please someone explain how Spamassassin build the following strings:

```
Oct 17 14:00:30 server amavis[29497]: (29497-02) SA dbg: uridnsbl: domain amazonaws.com in skip list, host sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Oct 17 14:00:30 server amavis[29497]: (29497-02) SA dbg: check: tagrun - tag URIHOSTS is now ready, value: libcurl.so
Oct 17 14:00:30 server amavis[29497]: (29497-02) SA dbg: check: tagrun - tag URIDOMAINS is now ready, value: libcurl.so
```

on the first line info about host which sent an email.
For me is interesting where did the spamassassin get the next two lines? How he detected/found domain libcurl.so?

Thank you for any explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Comes from plugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::URIDNSBL

Comment: This answer needs explanation.

Comment: References
1 - https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.2.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Plugin_URIDNSBL.html
2 - https://www.apharmony.com/software-sagacity/2014/05/enable-and-test-uridnsbl-dns-blocklists-with-spamassassin/